# How to enable maven profile when built version is not -SNAPSHOT?

Tags: java, maven, maven-profiles, maven-javadoc-plugin, maven-source-plugin

I'm trying to use the [`gitflow-helper-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/egineering-llc/gitflow-helper-maven-plugin) extension for my maven builds.

Therefore I'd like to configure my project in order to run some extra steps when building a release version and skipping them while compiling a SNAPSHOT one, but I cannot find a way to enable a profile if `${project.version}` contains `-SNAPSHOT`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: are these extra steps concerning plugins having a `skip` option?

Comment: By now the extra steps are maven-source-plugin and maven-javadoc-plugin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Below a possible approach which is how you could always simulate an `if` statement in a Maven build:

- Use the `buid-helper-maven-plugin` and its `regex-property` goal to parse the default `${project.version}` property and create a new `${only.when.is.snapshot.used}` property with value `true` or `${project.version}` in case of `SNAPSHOT` suffix found.
- Configure the `maven-source-plugin` to execute its `jar` goal with a special configuration using its [`skipSource`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html#skipSource) option and passing to it the new (dynamic) `${only.when.is.snapshot.used}` property: in case of snapshot it will have value `true` hence skip the execution, otherwise will have value `${project.version}` which will be used as `false` and hence not skip this execution
- Configure the same as above for the `maven-javadoc-plugin` using its [`skip`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/jar-mojo.html#skip) option

A sample of the approach above would be:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- sets the only.when.is.snapshot.used property to true if SNAPSHOT was used, 
                to the project version otherwise -->
            <id>build-helper-regex-is-snapshot-used</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>regex-property</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <name>only.when.is.snapshot.used</name>
                <value>${project.version}</value>
                <regex>.*-SNAPSHOT</regex>
                <replacement>true</replacement>
                <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-sources</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- skip when version is SNAPSHOT -->
                <skipSource>${only.when.is.snapshot.used}</skipSource>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-javadoc</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- skip when version is SNAPSHOT -->
                <skip>${only.when.is.snapshot.used}</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

That is, no need for profiles, this configuration will only be enabled when a non SNAPSHOT version will be used, dynamically and without any further configuration (command line options or whatsoever).

---

As a side reminder, you could also look at the `maven-release-plugin`, which will effectively invoke the source and javadoc plugin only when [performing](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html) a release without the added (minor) complexity of the approach above.

Otherwise, you could simple use the default profile coming from the [Maven Super POM](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html) which would actually invoke the same, source and javadoc plugin, and can be activated via the property `performRelease` set to value `true`. That is, on any Maven project could you invoke the following:

```
mvn clean package -DperformRelease=true
```

or

```
mvn clean package -Prelease-profile
```

And you will automatically benefit from the default super profile and have sources and javadoc jars generated, although this approach should be used as last option since the profile could be dropped from the super pom in future releases.

Comment: Based on this fantastic response: https://plus.google.com/112346331375070267873/posts/AntD8wE1F3b?hl=es

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you another solution.

Why don't you set version in profile instead of make decision about profile activation on version? Like here:

```
<version>${projectVersion}</version>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>snapshot</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <projectVersion>1.0-SNAPSHOT</projectVersion>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>release</id>
        <properties>
            <projectVersion>1.0-RELEASE</projectVersion>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: The idea gitflow-helper-maven-plugin is to use a single job in CI server (that triggers mvn clean deploy) in order to build the project. According to the branch that is compiling the artifacts get deployed to snapshots, stage or releases repositories. Version is managed by using versions:set goal when creating a new branch.

Comment: In this scenario I'm not able to activate specific profiles so I cannot use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/use-releases.html

use goal `mvn versions:use-releases`